# If they haven't heard of Islam .. Do they enter the hell?

Tags: fatwa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the fate of someone who died never hearing of Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/368/what-is-the-fate-of-someone-who-died-never-hearing-of-islam)

Allah says :

> **ومن يبتغ غير الإسلام دينا فلن يقبل منه وهو في الآخرة من الخاسرين**
>
> **And whoever desires other than Islam as religion - never will it be accepted from him, and he, in the Hereafter, will be among the losers**.

But also Allah says :

> من اهتدى فإنما يهتدي لنفسه ومن ضل فإنما يضل عليها ولا تزر وازرة وزر أخرى **وما كنا معذبين حتى نبعث رسولا**
>
> *Whoever is guided is only guided for [the benefit of] his soul. And whoever errs only errs against it. And no bearer of burdens will bear the burden of another*. **And never would We punish until We sent a messenger**.

So if someone haven't heared of Islam.. Whether he/she is Christian or a Jew or an atheist or otherwise..
Does she/he enter the **hell**..?

And what about who heard about Islam, but in a **distorted manner** ?

Comment: Exact duplicate, except the final part of the distorted manner, I wish you ask another question addressing that exact situation.

Answer (score 0):

There is a verse in the Quran

> **Soon will We show them our Signs in the (furthest) regions (of the earth), and in their own souls, until it becomes manifest to them that this is the Truth. Is it not enough that thy Lord doth witness all things? (Quran 41:53)**

So getting the message across **clearly** is the responsibility of Allah and Allah is the witness of this too.

In the above verse Allah takes the responsibility of showing people His Signs. It clearly says *"until it becomes manifest to them"*, so they would know it is the truth from Allah.

So even if a person is a Jew, Christian or a non-practicing Muslim, they would at some point in their life know Islam is the truth and it becomes their responsibly to accept it.

One must remember that every one is born a Muslim. So if you remove the external influences of the world on a person from birth, the person will tend to be a Muslim.

There are instances where people have found tribes deep in forests who have not had contact with modern humans at all. The practices and religion of these tribes is very similar to Islam. Like belief in one God or they do the sajud when they pray etc.

So Allah is the Best of Guides...