# If they heard about Islam, but in a distorted manner will they go to the hell or heaven?

Tags: fatwa

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the fate of someone who died never hearing of Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/368/what-is-the-fate-of-someone-who-died-never-hearing-of-islam)

Suppose that we have a person has heard about Islam, but in a distorted manner. Or if they know *of* Islam but don't know *about* it.

Will this person go to the hell or heaven?

Comment: no it's different situation because the person here has heared of islam.. but maybe he know bad ideas or few ideas may doesn't make him desire to Islam

Comment: No matter what, an atheist would go to hell - by definition they are against a belief in any god.  Someone who is ignorant has a chance if they live a good life - IMHO.

Comment: @AnwarShah: No it's not a duplicate, that question talks about who never heard about Islam, while this talks about who heard about it wrongly, like those who are shown Islam only as a religion of terrorism. See [this](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/2067/167) for differentiation :)