# What happened to people who were born and died before the Prophet's birth?

Tags: sharia, prophets, history

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the fate of someone who died never hearing of Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/368/what-is-the-fate-of-someone-who-died-never-hearing-of-islam)

Does Islam accept that there was life before the Prophet's birth? If yes, then at that time on what basis people were admitted to the afterlife?

Comment: Does this answer your question - http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/370/38 ?

Comment: @Ershad, Thanks for the reference. It seems that fate of the people who were ignorant of Islam until death was decided by one call (depending upon whether or not they will obey Allah or equivalently they accept the truth) at the entrance (heaven or hell). And for the people who were aware of Islam were judged by activities in their lifetime(depending upon sins they have committed). Is this not unfair?

Comment: The answer is only with reference to belief and disbelief. The fate of disbelievers is hell for eternity. The people to whom the call never reached are given a chance to prevent this to be fair. The answer says nothing about judging deeds. Allah says in Qur'an that every deed of the person will be judged justly. So, you don't have to be worried of unfairness, since Allah is the most just. Even among muslims, the sinners could spend time in hell for a while and then can go to heaven. However, the decision lies with Allah, he could forgive them. And he is the most Just

Comment: And to add, nobody can be sure of he is going to hell or heaven for sure. The surety is in only one thing - That is one who has faith will go to heaven *eventually* as only crime that entails eternal hell is Shirk and disbelief. That could even mean Allah forgives all his sins and he goes to heaven immediately or he could get punished for a while and then enter the paradise. So, it is not all black and white. So, it is better we don't judge the fairness of Allah's decision since as a part of faith, it is a must we believe him to be the most Just.

Comment: @Ershad, I am not worried at all. Indeed Allah is the most Just. When you said "Allah says in Qur'an that every deed of the person will be judged justly", will the people who were ignorant of Islam will be judged by Sharia laws? If no then by which standard people were judged? If yes, then that is unfair indeed as concerned people never new what was righteous path. If nothing can be said I am OK with it but just wanted to confirm it.

Comment: take it to the chat room please