# Propaganda, predisposition and belief

Tags: non-muslim, non-muslim-countries

Related to [this question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/368/what-is-the-fate-of-someone-who-died-never-having-heard-of-islam).

Now look at a slightly different case.

> Take the example of my grandma in China. She was from the era where people wholehearted support the communist regime. Throughout her life, what she had access to was Marxist ideology about materialism, to which she adhere to. Religion has always been mis-portrayed and shined negative lights on.

Now according to some, she did not receive a *just* representation of Islam, less so 'clear evidence'. But now suppose I tell her about Islam, and be as *just* as I can, it is almost certain she will not believe. Because she has this 80 years mindset, and it is as impossible as if you want to convert a pious old age Muslim to atheism!

Therefore, according to some she will be responsible for her denying the sign.

But my question is

> Take an arbitrary pious Muslim born in a Muslim family in a Muslim country. Suppose he instead lived a life of my grandma of 80 years of atheism propaganda, after which we tell him about Islam. It is very unlikely that he changes his mind. Doesn't this show a strong disadvantage toward those who were born in such a society (like my family and I)? If you really think about how a Chinese is brought up, there is great chance that he/she will not submit to God due to his family, childhood, education, propaganda from the government and the atheist society. How do I understand it in contrast to the fact that Allah is the Just?

**Addendum**
There is Muslim minority in China, but they only dwell in a (few) specific province(s). Except for those born in a Muslim family, there are **hadly any** people out of 1.3 billion who adopt/convert to Islam.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's fair to say it's "impossible" for someone to accept Islam just because they grew up in a distinctly unIslamic environment; God guides whosoever He wills.  I doubt the situation with your grandmother in China is significantly different than the situation of Muhammad himself in Makkah.

Don't forget: Muhammad didn't grow up in anything resembling an Islamic culture.  He was as much if not more of a minority preaching Islam — for all intents and purposes an unheard of religion to the people — to both the idol-worshipping Makkans and the people of the Book who lived in the area.

If you rely on human ability to convert people to Islam, then yes, the task is daunting.  But we don't guide people to Islam, we only convey the message.  It is God Himself who guides.

Answer (score -1):

This verse in the Quran doesn't answer your "big" question but it sheds some light on the situation of your grandma..

> **22:5** O people, if you are in doubt as to the resurrection, then We
>   have created you from dirt, then from a seed, then from an embryo,
>   then from a fetus developed and undeveloped so that We make it clear
>   to you. We settle in the wombs what We wish to an appointed time, then
>   We bring you out a child, then you reach your maturity, and of you are
>   those who will pass away, **and of you are those who are sent to an old
>   age where he will not be able to learn any new knowledge after what he
>   already has.** You see the land still, but when We send down the water
>   to it, it vibrates and grows, and it brings forth of every lovely
>   pair.

It seems that people of old age may be too set in their own ways and maybe too limited in acquiring new knowledge. You may try to reason with her to acknowledge that there's a God at least. Unfortunately, really, based on the verse above, you may just aggravate her more than anything :(

I tried with my grandma who's orthodox christian. And while she agrees with my message (God Alone), she continues to go back to her old ways.