# What will happen to people that never had any Prophet in their times to guide them on the day of the judgement?

Tags: non-muslim, day-of-judgement

I recently came across [Morgan Freeman's following answer](http://www.thewrap.com/tv/article/morgan-freeman-inventing-god-aliens-eating-us-and-his-odds-surviving-dark-knight-rises-42886/) about whether human beings invented God or not:

> So there isn't a God up in the sky somewhere. We came up with God
>   ourselves. Well, here's a scientific question: Has anybody ever seen
>   hard evidence? What we get is theories from our earlier prophets. Now,
>   people who think that God invented us think that the Earth can't be
>   more than 6,000 years old. So I guess it's a question of belief. My
>   belief system doesn't support a creator as such, as we can call God,
>   who created us in His/Her/Its image.

and immediately thought about the fate of the ancient people on the day of the judgement who never had any Prophet/Rasool/Nabi/Scripture at their times to guide them. What will happen to them? Will they go through the same process as all other people who had guidance in their times? Or Allah has always sent someone (Prophet/Rasool/Nabi/Scripture) in every age to guide people?

A logical answer would really help, thanks!

Comment: @Hakim No its not a duplicate. I am talking specifically about ancient people. Like immediate descendants of Hazrat Adam (AS) and Amma Hawa (RA).

Comment: Those people also fall in the category of those who never heard of Islam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Logical Answer:**

You might have heard this saying

"Religion was invented to keep masses under control"- Non Believer.

And also if you've read the Qur'an/Bible, you would understand the pattern of the examples given by the creator of the past who were **too arrogant** like of the Firaun(pharaoh), people of Noah(peace be upon him) etc.

> And never would your Lord have destroyed the cities until He had sent to their mother(town or main center) a messenger reciting to them Our verses(warnings and guidance). **And We would not destroy the cities except while their people were wrongdoers**. (Qur'an 28:59)

These are the extreme cases and so became good examples for us in the religious books Old testament, Qur'an etc.

What about those who did not do anything wrong?

Then, (suppose) the creator did not send any prophets to them feeling "Oh! They're fine and don't need a warning(prophet)."

If at all they were fine, then fine, **they'll be judged by the best of their deeds and will be punished as God wishes for their mistakes, and/or forgives as he wishes on the day of Judgement. As verily, the creator is All wise, and judges perfectly.**

But, is it really possible that they don't receive a warner at all by resisting without doing anything wrong. I don't think so,

> By time, Indeed, mankind is in loss, Except for those who have believed and done righteous deeds and advised each other to truth and advised each other to patience. (Qur'an 103)

The above verse has nothing to do with Islam, and is in general.

So, as time passes(generations pass), masses get out of control and need to be controlled.

**Straight forward answer:**

> And for every nation is a messenger. So when their messenger comes, it will be judged between them in justice, and they will not be wronged. (Qur'an 10:47)

So, when a set of people in a nation are reminded and warned, they warn their next generation, and their next and so on until, the message gets lost and/or deviated as time passes and so does God come with a fresh and new messenger/warner revising the main message and modifying the verses/message which need to be modified according to the generation.

May the creator guide us all

Answer (score 0):

in shiaa there is something name is RAJAT that say : all the peaple that couldn't see them prophet or Imam before them death , when the last Imam (Mahdi) arrival , they will be get alive again and pass will be in them Imam . in  this time they will choose them way . war with Imam or be friend . 
there is too many article in web but many of them are in persian language . my English is too poor for answer this question completely  .

Answer (score -2):

"Or Allah has always sent someone (Prophet/Rasool/Nabi/Scripture) in every age to guide people?"

1. We live in an age where there are many who claim prophethood, especially here in Africa.
2. We have no "God elected prophet"wandering the earth right now.
3. You have the God given ability to reason why we do not have what the ancient people had in their time.

**Answer**
We have three books freely available on the internet, The Thorah, The Bible, and
The Quran Chapter 20 verse 123
[ Allah ] said, "Descend from Paradise - all, [your descendants] being enemies to one another. And if there should come to you guidance from Me - then whoever follows My guidance will neither go astray [in the world] nor suffer [in the Hereafter].

**Reality**

We are all enemies to one another ,look at all the wars,violence to children, road rage ect but if we can understand and make sense of what is writen in the three books then we are gauranteed by the mentioned verse that we will not suffer in the hereafter

Comment: Again to my original question, what about those who never had "The Thorah, The Bible, and The Quran" or any messenger at their times for guidance ?