# What is the fate of a deceased baptized child?

Tags: christianity, baptism

In an answer to [this question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/368/4694), it is said that:

> Anyone who has not received the Da`wah (Invitation to Islaam) in the life of this world and died ignorant of the truth will be tested on the Day of Resurrection

A small child that is incapable of grasping the concept of religion and divinity cannot have received a "clear evidence", or "messenger with clear proof".

> And We never punish until We have sent a Messenger (to give warning). [17:15]

A baptism is a Christian ritual, and you are "baptized into Christ". Does this affect your fate in any way? Or to be more general, can your parents choices be crucial to your own fate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By baptism, do you *the child* accept in your soul that Christianity is right?
To me, it isn't the case.
It is a matter of personal belief. A child doesn't know that he's being taken into Christianity as he/she doesn't know what's religion and what's God and so forth.