# Is it the mistake of ours for not propagating Islam to non muslims or could it be a hole in islam?

Tags: practical-islam, allah, islamic-philosophy, non-muslim, punishment

[based on this question which i asked before:How could someone confirm with his/her's little knowledge (which he gained through his little research) that what he/she believes is the real truth? (REFER EDITED QUESTION))](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/47031/how-can-someone-confirm-his-her-faith-on-islam-is-the-truth/47039#47039)

Lets consider this example that there was a mother who had three sons. Those sons went to play some game at morning. Mom reminded them when they left that they should come home by afternoon and should remind each other to come back home.. but she was sure that they would forget while they were busy playing. But by afternoon it was seen that two boys came back as one boy reminded reminded the other. Well even though the two boys could have reminded the third boy they missed it. Is it the mistake of the children to remind the other or is it better mother herself go there by any means to call the third boy?

note: eventhough quran is sent as a message to all of humankind. we know that not every human in the world has got its message or read it. lakh of people died without getting the message in it.

if we were to look through this world we could see thousands of non muslims who are kind and good in every aspect. sometimes i feel why they weren't given hidayath and it really hurts to see them die as a non muslim when comparing with some people who born in muslim families.

the reason i linked to my before question is because, we know that its not because they(non-muslims) know or have proof to disbelieve islam, but they are non muslims because they were taught so by their parents like my mother was taught. usually the word fate has been used as a word for convincing people that, it happened so and so because god has written that way. Even though we know that not everything was already predetermined. isn't that act of saying that Allah has sealed their hearts or saying that that person had a different fate, an act of convincing to satisfy ourselves. Or is it a hole in islam to answer such questions?

so my question is **Is it the mistake of ours for not propagating Islam to non muslims or could it be a hole in islam claiming such reasons?**

this question is based on the pain i feel when i hear some non muslims i know die without getting the true message we know. i feel there's something wrong with this whole test of life. want to clarify it. hoping to get a fruitful answer.

continuation of this question: [if islam is the universal truth why is  chrstanity still the largest religion?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/47147/if-islam-is-truth-y-chrstanity-is-still-the-largest-religion-why-couldnt-god-m/47168#47168)

Answer (score 3):

May Allah guide your mother and other non-muslims to the straight path. *Ameen*.

It is from the justice of Allah that He does not punish any people until He has first sent a warning to them and unless there is evidence against them.

> Whoever is guided is only guided for [the benefit of] his soul. And
>   whoever errs only errs against it. And no bearer of burdens will bear
>   the burden of another. **And never would We punish until We sent a
>   messenger.**
>
> [Quran (17:15)](https://quran.com/17/15)

Allah also says in the Quran that each individual who is cast into the Hell will have being sent a warner:

> It almost bursts with rage. **Every time a company is thrown into it,
>   its keepers ask them, "Did there not come to you a warner?" They will
>   say," Yes, a warner had come to us, but we denied and said, ' Allah
>   has not sent down anything.** You are not but in great error.' " And
>   they will say, "If only we had been listening or reasoning, we would
>   not be among the companions of the Blaze." And they will admit their
>   sin, so [it is] alienation for the companions of the Blaze.
>
> [Quran (67:8-11)](https://quran.com/67/8-18?translations=20)

Each person will asked about the messenger/prophet of their era. All Prophets of God preached the same message of his Oneness and to associate no partners with Him.

For our ummah, a person who has never heard of Islam or the Prophet, and who has never heard the message in its correct and true form, will not be punished by Allah if they dies in a state of disbelief. If it were asked what their fate will be, the answer will be that Allah will test them on the Day of Resurrection: if they obey, they will enter Paradise and if they disobey he will enter Hell.

The evidence for this is the hadeeth of ***al-Aswad ibn Saree***, who reported that the Prophet of Allah said:

> “There are four (who will protest) to Allah on the Day of
>   Resurrection: the deaf man who never heard anything, the insane man,
>   the very old man, and the man who died during the fatrah (the interval
>   between the time of Jesus and the time of Muhammad).
>
> The deaf man will say, ‘O Lord, Islam came but I never heard
>   anything.’ 
>  The insane man will say, ‘O Lord, Islam came but the
>   children ran after me and threw stones at me.’ 
> The very old man will
>   say, ‘O Lord, Islam came but I did not understand anything.’ 
>  The man
>   who died during the fatrah will say, ‘O Lord, no Messenger from You
>   came to me.’
>
> Allah will accept their promises of obedience, then Word will be sent to
>   them to enter the Fire. By the One in Whose Hand is the soul of
>   Muhammad, if they enter it, it will be cool and safe for them.”
>
> According to another report, he said: “Whoever enters it, it will be
>   cool and safe for him, and whoever does not enter it will be dragged
>   to it.” (The hadeeth was reported by Imaam Ahmad and Ibn Hibbaan, and
>   deemed saheeh by al-Albaani, Saheeh al-Jaami’, 881).

And Allah knows best.

Comment: A continuation of this question. Pls answer that too.. https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/47147/if-islam-is-truth-y-chrstanity-is-still-the-largest-religion-why-couldnt-god-m

Answer (score 2):

Humans certainly make mistakes in [dawah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawah) (preaching of Islam).  For example, it's not a challenge to find fatawa which describe "the West" with significant contempt.

> ... the west has shown its true colours with regard to so-called religious freedom and freedom of self-expression.
> <sub>[Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/22309)</sub>
>
> In a media that is controlled by corrupt people, women who adhere to Hijab are considered as a clear evidence for her humility, backwardness degradation, ignorance … etc. On the other hand, trading with women’s bodies was never considered as such…!!
> <sub>[IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/en/article/135294/domestic-violence-against-women-in-the-west--i)</sub>

This Islam vs. the West attitude deters people from converting to Islam: it sends the message that the West and Islam are incompatible, not just to people who might convert, but also to their families and friends.

[Yaqeen Institute](https://yaqeeninstitute.org/en/homepage/) has a graphic which depicts the [modern pathways to doubt](https://yaqeeninstitute.org/en/youssef-chouhoud/modern-pathways-to-doubt-in-islam/); it "examines the reasons for Muslims in America losing their belief in Islam".  This gives other major obstacles relevant to propagating Islam.

That being said, failing to propagate Islam to the whole globe is not necessarily an individual's or a group's mistake.  There have been myriad geopolitical factors throughout history that contribute towards this.  E.g. the language barrier: throughout history large amounts of Islamic information have not been available in English.  It's still a problem today.

It's also important to be aware that the Qur'an states:

> Indeed, those who disbelieve - it is all the same for them whether you warn them or do not warn them - they will not believe.  Allah has set a seal upon their hearts and upon their hearing, and over their vision is a veil. And for them is a great punishment.
> <sub>[Qur'an 2:6-7](https://quran.com/2/6-7)</sub>

Therefore, we can expect to be incapable of persuading certain people from converting to Islam.

And obviously, Muslims believe that God does not make mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

In today's world, the fault lies with both the people who disbelieve and the believer if they didn't remind them. To show this let me tweak the example you made:

The mother gave each of the children a letter in their pockets (Quran) that reminds them to come back in the afternoon. Now, we can clearly see that the third child is at fault for not reading the letter and listening to it. But the other two children also deserve a bit of the blame for not reminding their brother when they should have.

God does not make mistakes. Everything that happens is by his plan. Why doesn't he make everyone muslim?

> And We have revealed to you, [O Muhammad], the Book in truth, confirming that which preceded it of the Scripture and as a criterion over it. So judge between them by what Allah has revealed and do not follow their inclinations away from what has come to you of the truth. To each of you We prescribed a law and a method. Had Allah willed, **He would have made you one nation [united in religion], but [He intended] to test you in what He has given you;** so race to [all that is] good. To Allah is your return all together, and He will [then] inform you concerning that over which you used to differ.

That is why the mother doesn't go out and remind herself. She intends to test the children and see which ones obey her.

Comment: sorry.. i made a little edit in my question. but i couldnt understand? how could crores of people be without getting the message of the Quran. how could you justify this act? not one but crores. and they include some of the brilliant minds lived in this world.

Comment: @Peaceman . What do you mean? The majority of people living right now have access to the Quran. It's just one click away on the internet. If they don't, that is a different situation, and Allah will deal with those few people who didn't have access to the Quran justly: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/368/what-is-the-fate-of-someone-who-died-never-having-heard-of-islam