# Since God has created us to test us with this life. Why couldn't God make every human know clearly that islam is the truth and keep this test of life?

Tags: allah, islamic-philosophy, non-muslim, atheism

BASED ON THIS QUESTION WHICH I ASKED BEFORE: [if islam is the universal truth why is christanity still the largest religion on Earth?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/47147/if-islam-is-the-universal-truth-why-is-chrstanity-still-the-largest-religion-on/47168#47168)

We know that not every non muslim has read quran or has got this message of the quran. well i agree that many may have heard of quran but the message in it will not be known by all of them. well its sad to say that, even many people who are born to muslims dont even know this message. well on adding the above data its seen that nearly 3996.9 million followers are non muslims who may be living with us right now. well more or less its clearly seen that a minimum of quarter of these people (999.225 million followers) may not have reached the true message of islam. well for our discussion lets consider that only 1 million in those people have not the real message.

even if that's the case how could 1 million people remain to be people who has not recieved message?
if u are teacher will u let go of those 1 millions students who doesnt even know that u will conduct a test in the end?

if u really want to keep a test to test them and if u have the real power to gather all those million student, wont u gather them and instruct them? isnt it wierd to hear that you will let them go and put for them grace marks for not attending the test even when you had the power to gather?

***Well SOME QUESTIONS may seem defend yourself type to them who don't know what to answer. For example this question ,"Who created God? or Can God create God?" may seem defend yourself type to some people. Since the reason someone couldn't answer, It doesn't mean no one can't. Well I think I know how to answer it. And devoting for such a reason is really not fair.***

Comment: Instead of insulting others you should learn how this site works, we answer focused and answerable questions this site is not made for discussions or debates. We are not interested in opinions but widely accepted scholarly views anything else is off-topic. (also read [Meta: read this before declaring its not fair](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3324/read-this-before-declaring-its-not-fair)

Answer (score 6):

It is our role as Muslims to do so.

During the battles of Persia, Al-Muthanna ibn Hāritha needed extra help. 'Umar ibn al-Khattāb sent over Rab'i ibn 'Āmir with some extra forces to lend military aid to Al-Muthanna. Rostam Farrokhzād, the commander-in-chief of the Persian army, had questions using almost identical logic to the one in your question. The response of Rab'i ibn 'Āmir — explaining what Muslims should after the death of the Prophet — was:

> إن الله ابتعثنا لنخرج من شاء من عبادة العباد إلى عبادة الله - عز وجل - ومن ضيق الدنيا إلى سعة الدنيا والآخرة ومن جور الأديان إلى عدل الإسلام
>   فأرسلنا بدينه إلى خلقه لندعوهم إليه
>
> <sub>**NOTE.** My own translation, so treat with care.</sub>
>
> Allah has sent us to get whomever He wills from among His servants from worshiping Allah's servants to worshipping Allah, and from the narrowness of this word to the vastness of both this world and the Hereafter, and from the transgression of religions to the justice of Islam. He [Allah] sent us with His religion to His creation to invite them to His religion.
>
> <sub>— [Kalimāt Mudī'a pp. 98](https://al-maktaba.org/book/32310/98#p1)</sub>

It is obvious that nowadays when no prophets or messengers will play the main role in spreading Allah's message that it is our responsibility to do so. So it is your responsibility — and all of us as Muslims — to ensure that the one million Muslims who are misinformed, and the nearly 3996.9 million non-followers get the message, know of the test, and know what they need to do to pass the test.

Comment: Hope it would be useful if you could add some points about The below quoted example. The quoted example given below is from the link: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/47068/is-it-the-mistake-of-ours-for-not-propagating-islam-to-non-muslims-or-could-it-b .you could also go there and answer.

Comment: "there was a mother who had three sons. Those sons wentt to play some game at morning. Mom reminded them when they left that they should come home by afternoon and should remind each other to come back home.. but she was sure that they would forget while they were busy playing. But by afternoon it was seen that two boys came back as one boy reminded reminded the other. Well even though the two boys could have reminded the third boy they missed it. Is it the mistake of the children to remind the other or is it better mother herself go there by any means to call other inform the third boy?"